# Getting different results while running the same stored Access SQL query directly and through VBA excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Hey the following stored access query is giving POEventCode with "*NA*"  when it is run through VBA excel and is giving the correct result when directly run from access.Why is this anomaly?

```
SELECT D.[Event Code] & D.[Week Code] AS POEventCode, *  
INTO A
FROM (SELECT IIf([Advertisement type]='Tabloide','TAB',
    IIf([Advertisement type]='Flyer','FLY','NA')) AS [Event Code], 
    IIf(([Start Date]>[SD] And [Start Date]<[ED]), 
        [Month] & Right([WM_WK],2),'NA')  
        AS [Week Code], *  
    FROM [Feature A-Traits] AS C, [Event Code] AS B) 
AS D
WHERE (D.[Week Code]) Not Like '*NA*'  
    And (D.[Event Code]) Not Like '*NA*';
```

Comment: That is a pretty confusing looking SQL, what is it you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ADO running your query through VBA Excel then your wildcards need to be % not *, so:- `Not Like '%NA%'`

Comment: I tried to up vote this and then down vote (deciding I wasn't certain the validity of the answer after all).  I ended up with a net down vote, which was not intentional.  I seem to be unable to fix the problem right now, and I apologize.

Comment: @Smandoli - no problem. Please post again with more information if you can't get the Excel query to work with % wildcards (you will need them in both places in your query).